Material maps are not working
I really need some help. Could not find the issue, and I'm clueless where something went wrong.
I have an object with unwrapped UV map. And a material that should have metallic, glossy, and bump map applied. (Some topology on the bottom does not align, but it's ok for now)
Color texture works just fine. But metallic, gloss and bump won't :(
Displace and bump setting is enabled.


Here is the file, and test textures https://we.tl/t-xMLbPz2hsa

You are using the image texture's Alpha output when you are supposed to use the Color output:


Thanks! It worked :)

In addition to using the wrong output from your image texture nodes as mentionned by @moonboots, your material is also set up to have a pretty dull looking result.
Here's what it looks by just fixing the above issue:

And here's what it could look like with some tweaks and having things in the scene to populate the reflections:

That isn't to say that you have to make it look that way, but that the way the shader is used isn't really effective and could be either done better to give different results. Or if that's the result you want, then maybe it could be simplified to a diffuse shader with a bump map without much visual difference but way simpler management for you and the render engine.
I will be quoting Principled BSDF - Blender 4.3 Manual bellow.
Metallic

Blends between a dielectric and metallic material model. At 0.0 the material consists of a diffuse or transmissive base layer, with a specular reflection layer on top. A value of 1.0 gives a fully specular reflection tinted with the base color, without diffuse reflection or transmission.

Metallic from 0.0 to 1.0

Metallic map are most often only pure black or pure black, no shades of grey. Because its only job is to tell which parts are metall and which parts are not. There is technically no inbetween.
People will use grey tones when trying to approximate rare "mixed" scenarios like oxidization. Although technically you can't have both metallic and non-metallic, sometimes we do need to bend the rules and make tradeoffs to get the right result. But that should be done mindfully. I'd advise to read:
PBR - Dark Metals Strategy | LinkedIn
In addition, I doubt your material is even supposed to have any metallic parts aside from maybe the text parts. That should probably all be non-metallic, and let the "regular" scpecularity do the reflections.
But for the sake of going along with what you did, your map is a red-ish tainted color map. Blender will still read it as a BW map, but then again: it has grey tones:

A simple fix for that could be to plug a Math node after the metallic map, set to "Greater Than". This way, any pixel of a value greater than the node's threshold value will be pure white, and the rest pure black:

If you do not want metallic, unplug the metallic map altogether and set the metallic input to 0. If you want just the text parts to be metallic, use a greater threshold on the Greater Than node, like 0.99.
If you want to use the texture in the regular specularity, then you could somehow mix it with your current roughness, as it's what will dictate how rough/glossy the surface is.

Roughness

Specifies microfacet roughness of the surface for specular reflection and transmission. A value of 0.0 gives a perfectly sharp reflection, while 1.0 gives a diffuse reflection.

Roughness from 0.0 to 1.0

The noise texture you plugged in the Principled BSDF's Roughness is a mostly light gray texture with little variation:

Which means that all your reflections will be rough and matte, and very tame. Almost as if you had a Diffuse shader. Here's what it looks like if we remove all the other maps:

IF that's not your intention, you need both darken that texture a bit and let it have more contrast.
For that texture, a simple solution is to disable its Normalize option. If you want more control, use a color ramp node.
Reducing the size a bit can help, since very fine details seen from afar tend to "blend" together.
Here's what it can look like with Normalize Off and Scale 100:

Sheen

Sheen simulates very small fibers on the surface. For cloth this adds a soft velvet like reflection near edges. It can also be used to simulate dust on arbitrary materials.
Weight
Controls in the intensity of the sheen layer.

Weight from 0.0 to 1.0
Roughness
Roughness of the sheen reflection.

Roughness from 0.0 to 1.0

The weird thing here is that you plugged a Glossy map into the Sheen's roughness.
We don't really use Glossy maps in Blender, because we use a roughness paradigm. Roughness tells how rough a surface is, whereas glossy tells how glossy aka "not-rough" it is. It's the opposite system.
If you use the Principled BSDF, there's no glossy data to play with. Even if you used a Glossy BSDF, the only place you could use a Glossy map would be with a mix node to tell which parts should use the Glossy BSDF and which should use whatever other shader you use in the mix node. But that's not our case here.
In addition, you plugged it to the Sheen roughness, but leaving the Sheen weight at zero, so you are driving the roughness of a layer that isn't visible.
If you do want some velvety looking sheen on that material, I would plug that map in the weight instead. But honestly it looks weird:

Reflections need context
All my screenshots were made in Material Preview shading mode. If I were to switch to Rendered, it would look like this:

That is because Material Preview have an HDRi illuminating the scene and giving something for the reflections to send back. But the actual final render will only have what you give, and right now there is only a three point lighting system with little variation, which easily looks flat on what is basically a cube.

So in addition to make your material look good, you also need to work your scene so that it properly showcases your object.
